# Is it possible to request a user's full profile using DotNetOpenAuth and the LinkedIn Developer Toolkit?

Tags: c#, asp.net, linkedin-api, dotnetopenauth

When requesting an access token using DotNetOpenAuth, it is only authenticating a basic user profile.

at `Authorization.BeginAuthorize();`

Is there some way of asking the user to authenticate against their full profile, perhaps by specifying something in the token manager?

I know that when making a POST to the LinkedIn API, you add the scope parameter but is there any way of doing this using DotNetOpenAuth and the LinkedIn Developer Toolkit?

`https://api.linkedin.com/uas/oauth/requestToken?scope=r_fullprofile`

I can also see that in the LinkedIn Developer Toolkit there are many ProfileField enums for the full profile so I assume that they can be accessed in this manner. e.g.

`ProfileField.Industry`

`ProfileField.ThreeCurrentPositions`

Comment: You can do that using the Spring.NET Social extension for LinkedIn : http://www.springframework.net/social-linkedin/ You have an example using a specific scope here (line 31-33): https://github.com/SpringSource/spring-net-social-linkedin/blob/master/examples/Spring.ConsoleQuickStart/src/Spring.ConsoleQuickStart/Program.cs Then you can call the IProfileOperations.GetFullUserProfile() method.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I was looking for a way to do this too. You'll need to extend the LinkedIn Developer Toolkit.

[Download the source](https://github.com/deeja/LinkedInDeveloperToolkit)

Add the following function overload to `WebOAuthAuthorization.cs`

```
public void BeginAuthorize(Uri callback, IDictionary<string, string> requestParameters)
{
    this.Consumer.Channel.Send(this.Consumer.PrepareRequestUserAuthorization(callback, requestParameters, null));
}
```

Compile it and add a reference to it in your project (remove NuGet package if you were using it). Then you'll be able to call it from your code, like so:

```
WebOAuthAuthentication webAuth = new WebOAuthAuthentication(LinkedInTokenManager, null);
Uri callback = new Uri("http://your.callback.uri");
Dictionary<string, string> requestParameters = new Dictionary<string, string>();
requestParameters.Add("scope", "r_fullprofile r_network");
webAuth.BeginAuthorize(callback, requestParameters);
```

As for your second question, the profile fields ENUM is for passing into the `GetCurrentUser` method (and probably others) to specify what fields to return, for example

```
LinkedInService li = new LinkedInService(webAuth);
List<ProfileField> fields = new List<ProfileField>();
fields.Add(ProfileField.ThreeCurrentPositions);
fields.Add(ProfileField.Industry);
Person person = li.GetCurrentUser(ProfileType.Standard, fields);
```

These fields are then accessible on the `Person` object (fields that you don't specifiy are null).

Comment: thanks, the suggestion for extending the LinkedIn Developer Toolkit worked great.